# Issue with Red5 server

Tags: java, red5

I have installed Red5 server successfully and also am able to run the demos fine. Now, I want to create a sample red5 server application. I created a sample project according to the specific directory structure that Red5 requires. But, now when I try to open this project in Netbeans 6.8, I am unable to because both have a different directory structure. So, Netbeans doesn't consider it as a project. I actually want to convert this project to a war file, so I can deploy it to red5/webapps directory and then red5 deployer service can make project out it automatically. How do I convert this project to a war file? because in Netbeans I am unable to open it. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this will fully answer your questions but this is my configuration.

In the main red5 directory there is a file called project.zip, you can open it to get basic configuration files, directories structure and build files for ant (Pure Java build tool).

Using netbeans, you create a new free-form project and point it to the directory of your project. because of the ant build files the project will be recognized.

Netbeans provides it's own ant version but i prefer to install and use ant from command line. 
when you'll run ant in the project directory it will try to find dependencies and probably at first will complain that it cannot find ivy.

Ivy is a dependency manager that red5 project uses that can be found in the following URL: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.html

please notice that ant will tell you exactly where it searches for the required jar file, just download the ivy zip, unzip it, and place the jar inside it in the requested directory.

once ant will compile the project properly (just by running the commant ant), it will also create a war file under dist directory.

don't forget to add to your red5 netbeans project the relevant red5 jars in order for the project to compile properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am also prefer use ant from command line. I have two directory structures. One for source files and another for deployment.
[This example](http://code.google.com/p/strangers-chat/source/browse/trunk/ant/build.xml) helped me to start.